# How do I connect to a server on a dev machine?

Tags: ios, iphone, networking

I have a REST API on my dev machine. If an app is running on a real device, how do I connect?

At present, I am looking up the IP address of the machine on the local network and setting that as the domain in the app's Info.plist.

However, this is a nightmare because the IP address changes everywhere I go and sometimes it inexplicably won't connect.

Is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [OHHTTPStubs](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs) to deal fake data. At least now I can work on the UI without needing to be concerned with the network.